# Angular 7 clear input fields

Tags: angular, input, checkbox

I'm making a `form` in angular where I have a `checkbox` and two `input` fields. I want to make the `input` fields `disabled` and cleaned when the `checkbox` is checked. I managed to do the disabled part but when the fields are disabled they still got their value. How can I do the clean part? I only found ways doing it with buttons or angularJs stuff but those neither works for me.

HTML code:
Formatted HTML

```html
// other parts of form //

    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-checkbox formControlName="closed" class="form-control" color="primary" [(ngModel)]="disabled">
        Closed</mat-checkbox>
    </div>

    <div class="material-input">
      <mat-form-field class="form-group" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Open from</mat-label>
        <div class="timepicker">
          <input matInput readonly [disableClick]="true" placeholder="Open from" formControlName="openFrom"
            [ngxTimepicker]="startTimePicker" [format]="24" [disabled]="disabled">
          <ngx-material-timepicker #startTimePicker></ngx-material-timepicker>
          <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle [for]="startTimePicker"></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
        </div>
        <mat-error *ngIf="editForm.get('openFrom')?.errors && (editForm.get('openFrom').touched)">
          This field is required
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="material-input">
      <mat-form-field class="form-group" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Open to</mat-label>
        <div class="timepicker">
          <input matInput readonly [disableClick]="true" placeholder="Open to" formControlName="openTo"
            [ngxTimepicker]="startTimePicker2" [format]="24" [disabled]="disabled">
          <ngx-material-timepicker #startTimePicker2></ngx-material-timepicker>
          <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle [for]="startTimePicker2"></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
        </div>
        <mat-error *ngIf="editForm.get('openTo')?.errors && (editForm.get('openTo').touched)">
          This field is required
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please write your html code to help better you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use mat-checkbox onChange emitter. And in the component function do the following for value cleaning by using form group.

```
 onChange(args) {
  if(args.isChecked){
   this.editForm.get('openFrom').patchValue(null);
   this.editForm.get('openTo').patchValue(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghmdz1

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('input', {static: false}) input : ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>
  onChange(event: MouseEvent){
  let target  = event.target as HTMLInputElement
    if (target.checked){
      this.input.nativeElement.value = ""
    }
  }
}

// app.component.html
<div>
  <input type="text" #input>

  <input  type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)">
</div>
```